# Where to get custom controls for Winforms .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm wondering if I can get some custom controls in winforms .NET?  Is there any place? I'm looking for album control. (something like this: http://joomla15.sakic.net/gallery/78th-international-motor-show-geneva/#8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, [WindowsClient.NET](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/default.aspx) is a good source.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of places.

- [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) is a popular commercial
  option
- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=control) has a lot of
  code of varying quality
- [Google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS347US348&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+controls)
  and of course the goog has millions
  of hits to wade through if the above
  don't work out.

As for your specific control, I'm pretty certain I've seen a number of them on codeplex in the past.